# 2006 Accord - Can't unlock with either key fob or actual key

Tags: honda, accord, locks, door

I am currently locked out of my 2006 Accord, as I cannot get the driver door (or any other door, for that matter) to unlock.

When I try the unlock button on the key fob, the door locks make a light clicking noise, but don't actually open. If I then try to re-lock them with the fob, they make the louder click that they normally make when I lock my car.

When I try to use the actual key in the driver's door, I cannot turn it more than ~30-45 degrees clockwise (the rotation to unlock), or a little further than that if I press the remote unlock button while trying to turn the key. The lock knob does not move at all during this.
I can turn the key all the way counterclockwise without issue. I tried using some isopropyl and ethyl alcohol to de-ice the lock (since it is about -7C here today), but that had no effect.

Edit: Should mention that the lights and horn work normally during this, so I don't think the battery could be an issue.

Comment: This is a tough one. Were I in your shoes, I'd at least try changing the battery in the key fob. It may or may not be the problem, but it's worth a shot.